# Замена символа в строке

Tags: java

Из консоли вводится строка и символ. Определить сколько раз встречается данный символ и заменить в строке этот символ на верхний регистра.

Я определил сколько раз встречается, но как потом заменить символы на верхний регистр?

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Введите строку:");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;

        String a = scanner.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Введите символ:");
        char c = scanner.next().charAt(0);

        char result[] = a.toCharArray();


        for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if (result[i] == c) {
                count++;
            }


        }


        System.out.println("Кол-во вхождений:" + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: result[i] = (char)(result[i] - 32);

Comment: @ValeraKvip '9', 'б', '!'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    if (result[i] == c) {
        count++;
        result[i] = Character.toUpperCase(result[i]);
    }
}
String resStr = new String(result);
System.out.println("Кол-во вхождений:" + count);
System.out.println(resStr);
```